# How can I get Flutter to handle true background processing?

Tags: multithreading, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

My lead developer chatted with me about an issue we are running into with Flutter. We are building a mobile app and now we have hit a potential issue regarding threading. He said that Flutter by design is normally single thread. He thinks he can get more than one thread to work, but he can't wrap his head around how to get the threads to communicate with each other.

What we need is true background processing where something can be totally handed off to a separate thread to function then no matter where the app is at something can receive a notification from that thread to be able to correctly refresh the UI state.

A simplified example of this is:

- User uploads an image
- Image gets processed in a different thread
- Badge shows up saying something like "image is processing"
- Image processing thread gets completed
- Badge goes away

The badge / UI thread would have to be send something from the image processing thread in this example. How could we tackle this with Flutter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use isolates with send port and receive port to communicate between the Ui thread and the isolate.

[Flutter Isolate Example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7mxIfR9v6oY)

Here is a greater plugin to help you use plugins in an isolate [flutter_isolate: ^2.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_isolate)

Comment: The video implies basically moving “expensive” logic for a stateful widget off of the main thread into an Isolate (bkg thread) then coming back to the main thread with the computed data.  That workflow is still I/O blocking. Data processing moves across threads to keep the UI thread from getting busy and creating the perception of an unresponsive app. What we need is true background processing where something can be handed off to a separate thread to function then no matter where the app is at something can receive a notification from that thread to be able to correctly refresh the UI state.

Comment: Have you found solution for your issue? If so, please post your update.